# jwt.verify Doesn't exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im getting this error whenever I try to get, post ...

```
 Target class [jwt.verify] does not exist. in file /home/salem/Desktop/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 875
```

even though in my routes I don't use jwt.verify

Comment: You did not use jwt in your project ?

Comment: No not yet non of my routes have a Middleware for jwt verify

Comment: try : check in `config/app.php` in provider not exist facade `JWT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the folder and re cloned it from my repo and did composer install and I didn't face any error this time , guess it was a vendor issue

Comment: If you have resolved the problem permanently, remember to mark your answer as accepted by yourself (when you can).

Comment: 15 hours left till I can but thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

No need to re-clone.

1. go to [your_project]/bootstrap/cache
2. delete "routes-v7.php"
3. send request again

Found a bunch of 'jwt.verify' added to middleware over there.